# UWP Binding list of images

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am trying to bind list of urls to images.

```
 <VariableSizedWrapGrid Grid.Row="2"
                               Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ItemsControl  ItemsSource="{Binding Images}">
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding }"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </VariableSizedWrapGrid >
```

I have also tried to do it with converter as below:

```
var current = value as ObservableCollection<string>;
                if (current == null) return null;
                var result = new ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>();
                foreach (var item in current)
                {
                    result.Add(new BitmapImage(new Uri(item, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)));
                }
                return result;
```

Images property is ObservableCollection().

The result is really weird because in UI I can see just list of URL string - not images. Does anyone know how to solve that?

Answer (score 1):

> ItemsSource typically references a list of items. This can be a fixed list from a business object, or a list that's designed to fire notifications if the underlying data changes. The list might be a generic interface (for example IList) or a practical class that implements the collection interfaces that Windows Runtime data binding supports. When you display items in an ItemsControl, you can use the ItemTemplate property, the ItemsPanel property, or both to specify the appearance of the items.

For more info, see Remarks of the [ItemsControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.aspx).

We should be able to use the [ItemsControl.ItemTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx) that we can add the `DataTemplate` in it.

For example:

```
<VariableSizedWrapGrid Grid.Row="2"
                       Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding }">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</VariableSizedWrapGrid>
```

By the way we do not need to convert the string to `BitmapImage`, we should be use `Image.Source` to bind the `string`.

For example:

```
private ObservableCollection<string> current;

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    current = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    current.Add("ms-appx:///Assets/sunset.jpg");
    current.Add("ms-appx:///Assets/treetops.jpg");
    current.Add("ms-appx:///Assets/valley.jpg");
    this.DataContext = current;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You may try custom converter to convert URI into BitmapImage object if auto-conversion doesn't work.
Below is a converter to convert uri into BitmapImage.

```
public class UriConverterNormal : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        string relativepath = value as String;
        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
        bi.UriSource = new Uri(relativepath.Trim(), UriKind.Absolute);
        return bi;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And then Define converter in resource area of page or usercontrol whatever you are using.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
<c:UriConverter x:Key="UriConverter" /></UserControl.Resources>
```

And then use converter with image control as below

```
<VariableSizedWrapGrid Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
<ItemsControl  ItemsSource="{Binding Images}">
    <DataTemplate>
        <Image Source="{Binding imageUrl, Converter={StaticResource UriConverter}}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl></VariableSizedWrapGrid >
```

Comment: "You will need to convert URI into BitmapImage object". While you *can* do this, it isn't necessary, due to built-in automatic conversion.